# MSWord 2010-Sequential numbering

Tags: vba, ms-word, increment

This applies to VBA on a Word Document.

I am creating a fillable form on Word 2010 by using activex.

The blank form will be stored on a network drive where employees will be able to fill out the form as needed, and then send the filled form to an email. The person filling the form out will not save the document as it will send the completed form to an email where I can save it from there.

**Here's what I am after:**

**A:** Have the user be able to "click" into a text box and have it generate a number in a sequence, increment by + 1, each time the document is opened, starting at 15001

**B:** Same concept into a text box, but have the sequenced number be generated by a "Command Button"

Answer (score 0):

MS Word does not provide such of functionality.
I'd suggest to create MS Excel workbook or MS Access database (preffered) as a datasource.
Each time when user open form (click inside textbox or commandbutton), the macro should add new record to the database and return new number in sequence.

Steps to do:
1) Create new Access database and add new table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyData
(
ID PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
CurrentDate Date
)
You can add other fields if it's needed. I added *CurrentDate* to be able to to get statistic information about number of documents created day by day ;)
```

2) [Create new ADODB.Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and connect to the database using ConnectionString from http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

3) [Create new ADODB.Recordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using *CursorType = adOpenDynamic*

4) [Add new record](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get **ID**

That's all!

In case of trouble, let me know. I'll improve my answer.